# Find the coefficient of $x^{19}$ in the generating function of $f(x) = \frac{(1-x^{5})^5}{(1-x)^{10}}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, generating-functions

> Find the coefficient of $x^{19}$ in the generating function development of $f(x) = \dfrac{(1-x^{5})^5}{(1-x)^{10}}$

***My Attempt:***

Let $\mathbf{(I)} \ (1-x^5){^5}$, then $(1-x^5){^5} = \sum_{k=0}^{5} \binom{5}{k} \left((-1)^{k}\cdot x^{5k}\right)$

And let $\mathbf{(II)} \ \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^{10} = \left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}{\left(x^{l}\right)^{}}\right)^{10} = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \binom{l+9}{9}\cdot{x^{l}}$

**I'd like to find all values of $k,l$ for which we'll get $x^{19}$.**

as $k=0,l=19:x^{5\cdot(0)}\cdot x^{19}=x^{19}$, and the coefficient of $x^{19}$ is $\binom{28}{9}$

as $k=1,l=14:x^{5\cdot(1)}\cdot x^{14}=x^{19}$,
and the coefficient of $x^{19}$ is $-5\cdot \binom{23}{9}$

for $k=2,l=9:x^{5\cdot(2)}\cdot x^{9}=x^{19}$,
and the coefficient of $x^{19}$ is $10\cdot\binom{18}{9}$

for $k=3,l=4:x^{5\cdot(3)}\cdot x^{4}=x^{19}$,
and the coefficient of $x^{19}$ is $-15\cdot \binom{13}{9}$

Finally, the coefficient of $x^{19} = \binom{28}{9} -5\binom{23}{9} +10\binom{18}{9} -15\binom{13}{9}$

Is that True?

Comment: That seems to be 3296425, whereas the answer is 3300000

Comment: @almagest how would you know to find the answer? did you just calculated it yourself or there's a quicker way to verify the asnwer?

Comment: I can't be bothered to tangle with those things, but it is really fast to get a computer math program to spit out the answer, so I thought it was worth checking yours. Eg Mathematica command is Series[((1 - x^5)^5)/(1 - x)^10, {x, 0, 20}] which returns instantly.

Comment: @almagest `SeriesCoefficient` is even more to the point :)

Comment: @amd Yes. But since they take the same time, I like to see how fast the coefficients are growing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost correct! Since $\binom{5}{3}=10$ (not $15$), it should be
$$[x^{19}]f(x) = \binom{28}{9} -5\binom{23}{9} +10\binom{18}{9} -\color{red}{10}\binom{13}{9}=3300000.$$